# Force StandardOutputEncoding to UTF8

Tags: .net, encoding, utf-8, process

I'm looking to parse UTF8 characters from the standard output stream of another application in my C# project. Using the default approach, characters outside of the ANSI spectrum are corrupted when read from the process' standard output stream.

Now according to Microsoft, what I need to do is set the StandardOutputEncoding:

> If the value of the StandardOutputEncoding property is Nothing, the process uses the default standard output encoding for the standard output. The StandardOutputEncoding property must be set before the process is started. Setting this property does not guarantee that the process will use the specified encoding. The application should be tested to determine which encodings the process supports.

However, try as I might to set StandardOutputEncoding to UTF8/CP65001 the output as read, when dumped to a binary file, shows the same castration of foreign language characters. They are always read as '?' (aka 0x3F) instead of what they're supposed to be.

I know the assumption at this point would be that the application whose output I'm parsing is simply not sending UTF8 output, but this is definitely not the case as when I attempt to dump the output of the application to a file from the commandline after forcing the codepage of the commandprompt to 65001, everything looks fine.

```
chcp 65001 && slave.exe > file.txt
```

By this, I know for a fact that the application slave.exe is capable of spitting out UTF8-encoded standard output, but try as I might, I'm unable to get StandardOutputEncoding to do the same in my C# application.

Each and every time I end up dealing with encoding in .NET, I wish I were back in the C++ world were everything required more work but was so much more transparent. I'm contemplating writing a C application to read the output of slave.txt into a UTF8-encoded text file ready for C# parsing, but I'm holding off on that approach for now.

Comment: Hmm, after 9 years this does not have a documented failure mode yet.  You'd better redirect the output to file.bin and take a look at it with a hex viewer.  Editors are far too happy to try to guess at the encoding of a .txt file.

Comment: Hans, that's what I've been doing. I open all output in HxD (excellent hex editor) and inspect the bytes. The chcp method works, the StandardOutputEncoding doesn't. Actually, from what I understand, StandardOutputEncoding actually only reflects the Encoding of the StreamReader on top of BaseStream. I read the bytes straight from BaseStream and they're already all normalized to 0x3F there. StandardOutputEncoding would work if I'm getting gibberish, but I'm not, I'm getting non-ANSI characters replaced with a single character.

Comment: it does not really answer your question but this solution also solves the problem of standard output redirection of a process: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ddietric/archive/2010/11/08/decoding-standard-output-and-standard-error-when-redirecting-to-a-gui-application.aspx

Comment: @fonzo I think it does. Thanks a lot for that link, I'll sit down with it and my code when I get the chance and report back.

Comment: An archived copy of @jeremy-george's link: https://web.archive.org/web/20151010090201/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ddietric/archive/2010/11/08/decoding-standard-output-and-standard-error-when-redirecting-to-a-gui-application.aspx -- this, like the modern `Console.OutputEncoding` property, are for console applications and won't work for GUI/winmain programs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only effect that StandardOutputEncoding has no impact whatsoever on the stdout of the executed application. The only thing it does is set the encoding of the StreamReader that sits on top of the binary stdout stream captured from the application being run.

This is OK for applications that will natively output UTF8 or Unicode stdout, but most Microsoft utilities do *not* do so, and instead will only encode the results per the console's codepage. The codepage of the console is manually set with the WIN32 API `SetConsoleOutputCP` and `SetConsoleCP`, and needs to be manually forced to UTF8 if that's what you'd like to read. This needs to be done on the console the exe is being executed within, and to the best of my knowledge, cannot be done from the host's .NET environment.

As such, I have written a proxy application dubbed UtfRedirect, the source code of which I have published [on GitHub](https://github.com/NeoSmart/UtfRedirect) under the terms of the MIT license, which is intended to be spawned in the .NET host, then told which exe to execute. It'll set the codepage for the console of the final slave exe, then run it and pipe the stdout back to the host.

Sample UtfRedirector invocation:

```
//At the time of creating the process:
_process = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo =
                        {
                            FileName = application,
                            Arguments = arguments,
                            RedirectStandardInput = true,
                            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                            StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                            StandardErrorEncoding =  Encoding.UTF8,
                            UseShellExecute = false,
                        },
                };

_process.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
_process.StartInfo.FileName = "UtfRedirect.exe"

//At the time of running the process
_process.Start();

//Write the name of the final slave exe to the stdin of UtfRedirector in UTF8
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(application);
_process.StandardInput.BaseStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
_process.StandardInput.WriteLine();

//Write the arguments to be sent to the final slave exe to the stdin of UtfRedirector in UTF8
bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(arguments);
_process.StandardInput.BaseStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
_process.StandardInput.WriteLine();

//Read the output that has been proxied with a forced codepage of UTF8
string utf8Output = _process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: You can use P/Invoke (DllImport) to call `SetConsoleOutputCP` and `SetConsoleCP` from .NET code.

Comment: Luaan, do you actually have access to the handle for the actual console .NET uses internally to pass to `SetConsoleOutputCP`?

Comment: Hello Mahmoud,Now I am in the same situation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22379643/encoding-utf8-c-sharp-process/22381000?noredirect=1#22381000. I tried your solution with UtfRedirect.exe. It didn't seems to help me. Any chances of am I doing anything wrong? I am reading an output from a VBScript instead of your slave.exe. Except that everything seems to be same.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi You actually don't need it, the methods only work with *your* console, you can't force someone else's console (by handle). However, if you need to capture the console you were started in, you can use the `AttachConsole` Win API method. Or to create a new console, `AllocConsole`. Also, you can run `chcp 65001` in the console to change the CP, I've described this in an answer to SeeEM's question (basically, run `chcp 65001 && otherApp.exe`).

Answer (score 4):

modern .NET option:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

[Source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Console/src/System/ConsolePal.Windows.cs#L113)

Comment: Perfect one-liner, just used at the start of the app/in static constructor and now able to pipe UTF-8 as strings.

Comment: This is the output encoding of the console tied to your application (i.e. your command line console's `conhost.exe` instance). GUI applications don't have a console.