# Encoding UTF8 C# Process

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, process

I have an application which process the vbscript and produces the output.

```
private static string processVB(string command, string arguments)
{
    Process Proc = new Process();
    Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    Proc.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    Proc.StartInfo.StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    Proc.StartInfo.FileName = command;
    Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    Proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; //prevent console      window from popping up
    Proc.Start();
    string output = Proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string error = Proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(output) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
    {
        output = error;
    }
    //Console.Write(ping_output);

    Proc.WaitForExit();
    Proc.Close();

    return output;
}
```

I think I have set everything related to Encoding property correct. processVB method will get command as VBscript file and its arguments.

The C# method processVB which is processing that VBScript file now producing the output as follows.

"����?"

But I should get original text

"äåéö€"

I have set Encoding correctly. But I am not able to get it right.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520706/force-standardoutputencoding-to-utf8 - I think that this is exactly your problem.

Comment: Yeah I have seen it. Thanks for the reference. No It didn't solve my issue.

Comment: The link explains the root of the problem.

Comment: What does CurrentEncoding property has for the StandardOutput right after starting the Process?

Comment: @cellik: System.Text.UTF8Encoding

Answer (score 3):

This answer is not answering direct question - but I noticed a deadlock potential in your code and thus thought it would be worthy to post it anyhow.

The deadlock potential exists due to your code trying to do synchronous read from redirected output, and doing it for both, StdOut and StdErr.  I.e. this section of the code.

```
Proc.Start();
string output = Proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string error = Proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

...

Proc.WaitForExit();
```

What can happen is that child process writes a lot of data to StdErr and filling up the buffer.  Once buffer gets filled up, the child process will block on the write to StdErr (without signaling yet end of StdOut stream).  And so child is blocked and not doing anything, and your process is blocked waiting for child to exit.  Deadlock!!!

To fix this, at least one (or better both) streams should be switched to asynchronous mode.

See [second example in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) that talk specifically about this case scenario, and how to switch to asynchronous mode.

As for the `UTF-8` issue, are you sure that your child process is outputting in this encoding and not say in `UTF-16` or some other one?  You may want to examine the bytes to try to reverse out what encoding stream is supplied in so you can set proper encoding for interpreting redirected stream.

**EDIT**

Here is how I think you can resolve the encoding issue.  The basic idea is based on something that I once needed to do - I had Russian text in unknown encoding, and needed to figure out how to convert it so it shows proper characters - take the bytes captured from StdOut, and try to decode them using all known code pages available on the system.  The one that looks right is *likely (but not necessarily)* the encoding that StdOut is encoded with.  The reason it is not guaranteed to be the one even if it looks correct with your data is because many encoding have overlap over some ranges of bytes that would make it work the same.  E.g. ASCII and UTF8 would have the same bytes when encoding basic Latin characters.  So to get exact match, you may need to get creative and test with some atypical text.

Here is the basic code to do it - adjustments may be necessary:

```
    byte[] text = <put here bytes captured from StandardOut of child process>

    foreach(System.Text.EncodingInfo encodingInfo in System.Text.Encoding.GetEncodings())
    {
        System.Text.Encoding encoding = encodingInfo.GetEncoding();
        string decodedBytes = encoding.GetString(bytes);
        System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Encoding: {0}, Decoded Bytes: {1}", encoding.EncodingName, decodedBytes);
    }
```

Run the code and manually examine the output.  All those that match the expected text are candidates for being the encoding used in StdOut.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out deadlock issue.I will resolve it. But UTF16 or other encoding also doesn't seem to work. I have tried everything :(

Comment: @SeeEM I just edited my answer (see section with bold **EDIT**).  I think this way you should be able to figure out the encoding used.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the console isn't UTF-8 by default. It runs in the same code page as your locale settings in Windows. A simple way to solve this is by using the `chcp` console command. Example:

```
chcp 65001 && yourScript.vbs
```

This will cause the output to be in UTF-8 and ensure that you can read it properly from your .NET application.

Note that I've tested this with a `bat` script instead of VB-script, but if VB-script does support UTF-8, it should work just fine. Also, you may have to explicitly call the VB-script execution engine instead of just `yourScript.vbs`. But you should be able to resolve this easily on your own :)

Comment: It didn't seem to work for VBScript. I am getting error "A device attached to the system is not functioning".

Comment: I've seen that error too. It seems that there are some issues with UTF-8 console - if the console doesn't have a font that supports UTF-8 (eg. `Lucida Console` or `Consolas` - don't use `Raster Fonts`), it seems that it simply doesn't work at all, even if you don't really need the console to be visible for anything at all.

Comment: Based on your comment from Mahmoud Al-Qudsi Question I tried running the process by `AttachConsole` and `SetConsoleCP`. But that doesn't seem to work. And we can't directly invoke chcp 65001 && yourScript.vbs using process in C# right?

Comment: @SeeEM Well, you can start a new process with the `chcp 65001 && yourScript.vbs` "command". That might be enough. Now, since you can't use `UseShellExecute`, you'll have to run `chcp 65001` first (or use `SetConsoleCP`?) and your script separately after that - the `&&` operand is part of the shell, not a "real" process. Also, try setting the font default for the console to `Consolas` or `Lucida Console` to see if it resolves the issue. As I've said before, it doesn't work for me with the default `Raster Fonts` setting for some reason.

Comment: @SeeEM Also, you should be able to set the console font programmatically using `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx`.

Comment: `SetConsoleCP` didn't work. I tried setting it to 65001. But it didn't work for the console associated with the process.

Comment: @SeeEM Have you changed the font? As I've said before, the default one doesn't support unicode at all. Bad things happen.

Comment: Yes I changed it @Luaan. :(

Comment: Instead of using Process Class, I used `CreateProcess` directly and passed the params. Then as you mentioned I set `SetConsoleOutputCP` to 65001.(I can set the chcp value for the console occupied by the Process only by using Native API CreateProcess()) Now I got the expected output in console :). But how can I redirect it and collect in a variable, like `Proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` ? Do you have any idea?

Comment: @SeeEM You might have to manually create a pipe and work with that; try something like this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

> Because the output that VBScript generates is UTF8

That's the assumption that is getting you in trouble here, it just isn't utf-8.  Nor can it be, the scripting engine doesn't support setting it.  Something you can try for yourself, use this statement in a sample .vbs file:

```
 SetLocale 65001
```

Kaboom, it only accepts LCID values and they don't cover utf encodings.  Instead, the cscript.exe scripting engine already changes the default code page itself.  Instead of the default OEM code page (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage\OEMCP value), it switches to the default Windows code page.  The ACP value in the above documented registry key.  Depends on your location, it will be 1252 for example in the Americas and Western Europe.

Some VBScript code to play with, be sure to save the file with the default encoding that's appropriate for your locale or the script interpreter itself will mis-interpret the strings in the source code.  Which in itself can explain your problem as well:

```
WScript.Echo "Locale: " & GetLocale
WScript.Echo "äåéö€"
WScript.Echo "Changing locale to US-English:"
SetLocale 1033
WScript.Echo "äåéö€"
```

Output on my machine:

```
C:\temp>cscript test.vbs
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Locale: 1033
äåéö€
Changing locale to US-English:
äåéö€
```

So the proper line of code in your program should be:

```
Proc.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.Default;
```

Do note that this is *not* the default that the Process class uses, it will assume that a console mode program uses the OEM code page.  Like 437 on a machine in Northern America and Western Europe.  You can pick another LCID in your .vbs program and change your C# code to match but that should not be necessary.

And do keep the failure mode of having the .vbs source code file encoded wrong in mind.  The scripting engine doesn't support utf-8 with a BOM either, unfortunately.

Comment: I got, 
`Locale: 1033
,+,"?
Changing locale to US-English:
,+,"?`
When I executed the same with `Proc.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.Default;`:(

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48436394/1840794)

Maybe it's also related to the process output ....

Answer (score 0):

The other process (vbscript) generates and output in some encoding. By setting the StandardOutputEncoding you tell the system how to read that stream. This will not change the Encoding made by the other process.

So you need to figure out the exact encoding used by the other process (VBScript). For that I'd run the script directly from the shell and redirect the output to a file and open it in an tool that shows the encoding (i.e. notepad2) And if I'm right that would be something other than UTF8.

Then you set the Proc.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding to that encoding in your code and then everything should work.

Comment: The output should be parsed in UTF8, Because the output that VBScript generates is UTF8. I have even tried other encoding formats too. But that didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

I am using your function like this:

```
label1.Text = processVB("wscript.exe", "c:\\s.vbs");
```

And my vbs file is

```
Set fso = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set stdout = fso.GetStandardStream (1)
stdout.WriteLine "äåéö€"
```

My vbs file is encoded as UTF-8 without BOM

And it works as expected. I see `äåéö€` on my form.

Maybe you should change the way how you use your function, encoding of your vbs file and how you output data to stdout.